# How to look up values in a data frame a populating a vector?

Tags: r

I have two data frames I would like to find the corresponding price based on the first column and another column.

```
v1<-c("Dec 1999",    "Oct 1999",    "Jul 1999",    "Apr 1999",     "Jan 1999")
v2<-c("Jan 2000",    "Nov 1999",    "Aug 1999",    "May 1999",     "Feb 1999")
v3<-c("Mar 2000",    "Jan 2000",    "Oct 1999",    "Jul 1999",     "Apr 1999")
v4<-c("Apr 2000",    "Feb 2000",    "Nov 1999",    "Aug 1999",     "May 1999")
v5<-c("May 2000",    "Mar 2000",    "Dec 1999",    "Sep 1999",     "Jun 1999")
Df1<-data.frame(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5)
colnames(Df1) <- c("condition1", "condition2.1", "condition2.2", "condition2.3", "condition2.4")


v6<-c("Dec 1999",    "Nov 1999",    "Jul 1999",    "Apr 1999",     "Jan 1999")
v7<-c("Jan 2000",    "Feb 2000",    "Aug 1999",    "Feb 1999",     "Feb 1999")
df2<- data.frame(v6,v7)
colnames(df2) <- c("col1", "Col2")
df2$Prices<-seq(1,length(df2$col1),by=1)
colnames(df2)[3] <- c( "prices")
```

I want to create a table which has:

df$condidition1 | condition2.1 | (the corisponding rpice from df2$price) | condition2.2 | (the corisponding rpice from df2$price) | ....

How would you go about doing this?  I tired a few different things and none seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

This is not very clear, you should add the output you expect.

But I think you are looking for something like `merge`.

Maybe :

```
> merge(df1, df2, by.x = c("v1", "v2"), by.y = c("col1", "col2"), all.x = TRUE)
        v1       v2       v3       v4       v5 prices
1 Apr 1999 May 1999 Jul 1999 Aug 1999 Sep 1999     NA
2 Dec 1999 Jan 2000 Mar 2000 Apr 2000 May 2000      1
3 Jan 1999 Feb 1999 Apr 1999 May 1999 Jun 1999      5
4 Jul 1999 Aug 1999 Oct 1999 Nov 1999 Dec 1999      3
5 Oct 1999 Nov 1999 Jan 2000 Feb 2000 Mar 2000     NA
```